# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied On GradeScope

Tags: java, exception

I am working on CS61B SP21 PROJ3. I finally make a game locally and try to push it to GradeScope.

However I find that GradeScope constantly tell me that " java.security.AccessControlException: access denied" when it reads from the file. It is Ok to read from or write in the files locally. So I am very confused about that.

How can I solve the bug....

I tried different ways to read/write contents, but GradeScope says they are all "wrong".

Mistake Message below:

```
Test Failed!
    java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/autograder/course-materials/proj/proj3/grader/phase2/submit/SaveWorld.dat" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission:472 (AccessControlContext.java)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission:1036 (AccessController.java)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission:408 (SecurityManager.java)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead:747 (SecurityManager.java)
    at java.io.File.exists:818 (File.java)
    at byow.Core.WorldSaveRead.saveWorld:16 (WorldSaveRead.java)
    at byow.Core.Engine.interactWithInputString:71 (Engine.java)
    at AGTestWorldGen.testSaves:193 (AGTestWorldGen.java)36 21
```

Comment: I think it does not. It seems like happens locally. I can create/read/write contents locally